# Can't get Drawable id with R in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1 with SDK API 23. i add some image to my res/drawable directory. one of my image name is `page0.png`. the i try to get the id of image with R so i try :

```
R.drawable.
```

but after drawable i have only has `class` property :

```
R.drawable.class
```

so i try these solution to fix this problem but nothing happen.

- Invalidate and Restart Android Studio
- Clean and Build Project
- Clean and Rebuild Project
- Checking import syntax of R, so R is exactly my R not android.R
- Exit and Restart Android Studio
- Creating new project and Test

and this is my part of gradle build setting :

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

and i cant use this syntax :

```
R.drawable.im1
```

update : 
[image]

Event Log :

```
  6:42:51 PM Gradle sync started
  6:42:54 PM Gradle sync completed
  6:42:55 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,              :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources,   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
6:42:57 PM Gradle build finished in 2s 457ms
7:02:45 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:02:47 PM Gradle build finished in 2s 345ms
```

Update : Project Hirarchy

[image]

Comment: Show us your project's hierarchy.

Comment: You are manually importing an `R` class. That's a bit unusual. Make sure this manual import matches your `package` in your manifest. You can examine the generated `R` class in the `build/` directory to see what's in there.

Comment: How did you import your image? were you using new Image Asset to import it?

Comment: @CommonsWare i can't see any R in my `build/` directory

Comment: @Kun I import my images with drag and drop in Android Studio.the a dialog come up and i hit ok without any error. i also try File explorer but i have same problem.

Comment: The `build/` directory contains subdirectories. There will be two `build/` directories, one off the project root and one in your `app/` module. In `app/build/generated/source/r/debug/`, you should find subdirectories for your package plus any dependencies. In there, you should find an `R.java` file.

Comment: In AS 1.5 I do get all suggestions when I type `R.drawable.` on a new line in an Activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes there is a R.java in the directory you said.but when i search for my image name, nothing found.

Comment: In which directory is im1.png? It's not in the dir that's expanded in your screenshot. Also, drawable-hdpi should not be a subdir of drawable.

Comment: @Christine my real image name is page0 and it's in all directory of hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi

Comment: Is the issue that the project was importing android.R instead of using the generated R file

Comment: @Kun i'm using `com.example.mohammad.interactivestory.R` not android.R. i pick R that suggest om.example.mohammad.interactivestory.R from android studio suggestion and then android studio add `import om.example.mohammad.interactivestory.R;` in my file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please move the `drawable-*` folders out of the `drawable` directory. `drawable-*` cannot be a subfolder of `drawable`; it should be a subfolder of `res`, just like `drawable`.

Comment: As you accepted this answer, did this solve your problem?